# How to make Git-Bash default terminal for IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, terminal, git-bash

I want to make Git-Bash default terminal for IDEA so that when I run the program using the run button, It should execute the program from 'Terminal' tab that I'd setup using 'sh.exe' rather than using the 'Run' tab.

Comment: What kind of app do you run? What's the type of the run/debug configuration?

Comment: I use IDEA for terminal based programs written in python. For Run/Debug config using python 3.10 with script path as current file (default). There's no such option to run the program from bash than the run tab.

Comment: How we use bash as default terminal for vs code where it execute the program, the same way I want with IDEA.

Comment: You can use external tools or Shell script run configuration for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a run configuration for a Shell Script. Then you configure the interpreter path to use the gitbash exe.

[image]

[image]